# DynamoDB update multiple items conditionally

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I want to update a DynamoDB item which has multiple fields but need to vary which fields are update on a case by case basis.

For example one request may want to update 2 fields (firstName & lastName) whilst another request may only want to update 1 field (firstName). I can not figure out how I can do this using aws-sdk without having multiple db requests.

I was thinking of doing a db lookup before, compare the fields and update the changed fields then update all fields.

However this just feels hacky.

```js
const firstName = "New Name";
const lastName = undefined; // to indicate the function was not passed this field to update

const updateParams = {
            TableName: `${dynamodb.tableNamePrefix}_merchants`,
            ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
            Key: {
                merchantId
            },
            UpdateExpression:
                'SET #firstName = :firstName, #lastName = :lastName',

            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                '#firstName': 'firstName',
                '#lastName': 'lastName'
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':firstName': firstName,
                ':lastName': lastName
            }
        };

        const updatedMerchant = await ddb.update(updateParams).promise();
```

Comment: I'm afraid I may be missing what the problem is. There is no problem with sometimes updating two attributes, and sometimes just one. You just can't use the same "updateParams" object for both types of updates, but so what? You definitely shouldn't have to read before you write.

Comment: Hi, yeah I just programically updated the Params based on what’s was required to update. I just thought there might be a way to handle it in the SDK kinda like batch PUT and DELETE.

Comment: I still don't understand what's wrong with having two versions of Params, one for updating two fields, one for updating one. It's definitely better than reading the old value first which you suggested as an option. Note that DynamoDB also has an older update parameter, "AttributeUpdates" instead of "UpdateExpression", which makes the entire Params object simpler, in case you're bothered by its length and ugliness.

Comment: Yeah that’s one way but it’s not the best way to handle it. The whole point of using a SDK is to handle cases like this. It just seams like a waste of time and code when the package should cater for it. I thought I was missing something. Cheers